# Symfony 2 - writing new method in entity class

Tags: symfony, entity

i'm trying to write new get method in my entity class

This is the property

```
protected $courseLink;
```

The get method for it

```
/**
     * Get courseLink
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCourseLink()
    {
        $this->courseLink = '/courses/'.$this->getCourseTitle();

        return $this->courseLink;
    }
```

The getCourseTitle method

```
/**
     * Get courseTitle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCourseTitle()
    {
        return $this->courseTitle;
    }
```

This is the controller with select query

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT c FROM DprocMainBundle:Courses c ORDER BY c.Id DESC'
    );
    $course = $query->setMaxResults(4)->getResult();
    //print_r($course);
    return $this->render('DprocMainBundle:Dproc:index.html.twig', array('courses' => $course));
```

print_r shows

Array

```
(
    [0] => Dproc\MainBundle\Entity\Courses Object
        (
            [Id:protected] => 1
            [courseTitle:protected] => 3ds Max и Vray
            [courseContent:protected] => 3ds max course is awesome!
            [courseCategory:protected] => 3ds-max
            [courseTeacher:protected] => Ваге Мурадян
            [coursePayment:protected] => payment..
            [courseSchedule:protected] => schedule..
            [courseDescription:protected] => description..
            [courseLink:protected] => 
        )

)
```

courseLink is null, but why? how should i give to it value in class then?

Comment: did you add the mapping information for the property? (annotations|yaml|xml) ... if yes did you run `app/console doctrine:schema:update`? ... **cleared your cache afterwards?** ... can you confirm the entry for `courseLink` actually exists in your database? Further doctrine sets the properties through reflection -> means you can't expect to have the dumped object to have the string "/courses" included - this will only be the result of calling the getter `$course->getCourseTitle()`

Comment: No no there is no mapping for that property because its not in database, thats just a method that display data. how should i do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `courseLink` property itself is **not** being stored in your database it will be `null` until you call the `getCouseLink()` method. That's actually the correct behavior.

Just pass the `$course` object you fetched from database to your view and access it like this:

```
{{ course.courseLink }}
```

Twig will call the `getCourseLink()` methdod which will return the correct string / url.

Comment: I got 2 questions, why {{ course.courseLink }} is calling the method getCourseLink but not the courseLink property. And why when i'm passing the $course to view, the courseLink property is null

Comment: The `$courseLink` property is null as long as you don't assign something to it ... which neither you nor doctrine (the property isnt mapped) do. Further as the `$courseLink` property is private/protected in `$course` ... twig only has access to the public getter. Therefore `course.courseLink` will make twig call `getCourseLink` to obtain the value. Got it?

Comment: Yes i got it, only thing i dont get, doctrine cant access to properties? he only work with getters/setters?

Comment: doctrine uses reflection to set those private/protected properties after fetching from database. doctrine will actually store the values of the properties by using reflection when saving to database - no getters involved there too. These getters used by other methods  (like the ones used by twig) to get the values because they don't have access to the properties.